# How to read parquet files from AWS S3 using spark dataframe in python (pyspark)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to read some parquet files stored in a s3 bucket. I am using the following code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# get a handle on the bucket that holds your file
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')

# get a handle on the object you want (i.e. your file)
obj = bucket.Object(key = 'file/key/083b661babc54dd89139449d15fa22dd.snappy.parquet')

# get the object
response = obj.get()

# read the contents of the file and split it into a list of lines
lines = response[u'Body'].read().split('\n')
```

When trying to execute the last line of code `lines = response[u'Body'].read().split('\n')` I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I'm not really sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of boto3 I had to use the following [code](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/127#issuecomment-214594895):

```
myAccessKey = 'your key' 
mySecretKey = 'your key'

import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.6.0 pyspark-shell'

import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext("local[*]")

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

hadoopConf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)

df = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://bucket-name/path/")
```